# Want to Get Parent Category Name than Child Category Name than post title

Tags: wordpress

How Can I get the below in WordPress custom post type

1. Parent Category Name 1

   1. Child Category Name 1

      1. Post title
      2. Post Title
   2. Child Category Name 2

      1. Post title
      2. Post Title
2. Parent Category Name 2

   1. Child Category Name 1

      1. Post title
      2. Post Title
   2. Child Category Name 2

      1. Post title
      2. Post Title

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code:

```
<?php 
$parent_terms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy_name', 'parent' => 0 ) );

if(!empty($parent_terms)){
    
    foreach($parent_terms as $parent_term){
        echo $parent_term->name;

        $termchildrens = get_terms('taxonomy_name',array('child_of' => $parent_term->term_id));
        if(!empty($termchildrens)){

            foreach($termchildrens as $termchildren){

                echo $termchildren->name;
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'cpt_name',
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy_name',
                        'field' => 'term_id',
                        'terms' => $termchildren->term_id
                        )
                    )
                );
                $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

                if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                        $the_query->the_post();
                        echo get_the_title();
                    }
                } else {
                    // no posts found
                }
                wp_reset_postdata();
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```